# how forbid access to DOM from JS

Tags: javascript, dom

I need create a sandbox to run a js on browser. I will run a code from the user, but the user cannot run commands that interactive with the page or browser (commands like open or document.getElementById)

I thought something like that:

```
(function(){
   var window = null;
   var document = null;
   var open = null;
   (function(){
       //user code here
   })()
})()
```

but I don't know if exist something more safe.

Comment: How about `<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts">`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support older browsers (e.g. IE9 or lower) then [Web Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) might be a good way to approach this problem. They are automatically sandboxed by the browser and have no access to the DOM.

I've created an [example JSFiddle that might point you in the right direction](http://jsfiddle.net/Ju59C/). The basics of getting it started is to have a script in the page like:

```
<script id="worker1" type="javascript/worker">
// This script won't be parsed by JS engines
// because its type is javascript/worker.

self.postMessage('I\'m about to run user code.');

// User code goes in here.
</script>
```

And the accompanying JS code is basically:

```
var blob = new Blob([document.querySelector('#worker1').textContent]);
var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

Comment: They might have no access to the DOM, but they still can run havoc in your app.

Comment: you know something more safe? 
because the user will send the script and this script will run in another user browser.